# Woocommerce All JS And Jquery elements are not loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I had made my theme to be compatible with woocommerce, by creating woocommerce.php, and adding a custom function in my functions.php file which is

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

And this is how my woocommerce.php file looks like :

```
<?php
                global $mandigo_options, $dirs;

                get_header();

                // heading level for page title (h1, h2, div, ...)
                $tag_post_title_single = $mandigo_options['heading_level_post_title_single'];
            ?>
                <td id="content" class="<?php echo ($mandigo_options['sidebar_always_show'] ? 'narrow' : 'wide'); ?>column"<?php if (mandigo_sidebox_conditions($single = true)) { ?> rowspan="2"<?php } ?>>

                    <div class="woocommerce">
                        <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
                    </div>




                </td>

            <?php
                // if we have at least one sidebar to display
                if ($mandigo_options['sidebar_always_show'] && $mandigo_options['sidebar_count']) {
                    if (mandigo_sidebox_conditions($single = true))
                        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebox.php');

                    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar.php');

                    // if this is a 3-column layout
                    if ($mandigo_options['layout_width'] == 1024 && $mandigo_options['sidebar_count'] == 2)
                        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar2.php');
                }

                get_footer();
            ?>
```

Everything is appearing fine now, but I can't find the add to cart button and also all the elements that uses javascript or jquery are not loading.

I had tried :

1. To use wordpress JQuery updater
2. To put the jquery library reference in the header.php
3. Deactivating all plugins

I had all the fields of the necessary elements in woocommerce field like the price, but its obvious that this is a JS or JQuery error.

And here is a link to the site is product page :

http://www.doctor-detail.com/product/gift-card-product-2

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When I inspected the site and checked the console I found that although I was linking to the latest jquery in the header of my site, it was using the main jquery of the theme.

So, all I needed to do is to remove the theme is Jquery file from the JS folder.

After that woocommerce was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wp_enqueue_script() in functions.php instead of linking in a header.php, Plese keep in mind JQuery in enqueued by default. If you need to change version, fist you have to deregister the default one.